# Secure/second access for web development - deny view for public; allow developer

Tags: apache

Sorry for the strange title, I can't find better description to my question.

I'm building some websites with a team of 4 persons - 2 developers and 2 testers. The developers build the page on a local apache/mysql server. Every now and then they upload a snapshot of what they have done to a dedicated server, that serves the files with htaccess basic authentification to the testers.

Are there better solutions for this workflow? I would like to have more security for this whole thing. The snapshots of the website often show debug-/development info, that shouldn't be seen by public eyes.

Something like a different port of the apache server... ? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think other way is to use Git or some other versioning system for deployment, so only new code will be added and you can disable showing of these debug informations permanently in some file which will not be overwritten.

OR

You can use some cloud service like getpantheon.com (for Drupal). It could provide you good environment for testing.